# Laravel Eloquent query 'with'

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have `users`, `images` and `image_user` tables. I am trying to eager load and get all the user with images but `limit` images to only 4.

*Think of it as a gallery. Where user can have one or many images*

User Model

```
public function images()
{

   return $this->belongsToMany(Images::class);
}
```

This is my query so far.

```
User::with(['images' => function ($query) {
   $query->limit(4);
  }
])->get();
```

This query returns user but with empty relationship (images)

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There's no easy built-in way to do this.

Check out Jarek Tkaczyk's excelent post on this subject:

**[How to get N related models per parent](https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-n-related-models-per-parent/)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = User::with('images')->limit(5)->get();
```

Are you aware of **php artisan tinker**? You can output data via your command line.

Try it with..

```
App\User::with('images')->limit(5)->get();
```

..and you'll see 5 users with images, providing your relationships are set up right.

**Edited**

Sorry, I didn't read your question right.

To limit the images returned for each user you could create a new method on your user model like so.

```
    public function imageslimit(){

       return $this->belongsToMany(Images::class)->limit(5);

    }
```

Pass all users to your view from your controller.

```
$users = User::all();
```

Then call when looping through all users in your view, just do.

```
@foreach($user->imageslimit as $image)

   $image->name; 

@endforeach
```

I tested this and it works fine for me.

Comment: I don think you get what I meant. I am trying to get images not user. The code you gave me is to get User limit 5 not User's Images and limit image by 4. BTW Yeah I do know php artisan tinker.

Comment: Edited, hope that's what you're looking for. It works fine for me.

Comment: This code will only load 5 images total. The OP want 5 images per user.

Comment: Yes but if he loops through each user so it'll return a maximum of 5 images each time.

Answer (score 0):

Use `take()` to take only 5 of the images.

```
$users=User::with('images')->get();
foreach($users as $user)
{
   echo $user->name;
   foreach($user->images->take(5) as $image)
   {
      echo $image;
   }
}
```

Comment: This only gets the first user. The OP said they need to fetch all users.

Comment: You're now loading all images from the DB.

Comment: @JosephSilber yes. loads all images and takes 5 for each user and could be an alternative if there are not much of records in the database. thank you!

Comment: Loading everything even if you don't need them is not an acceptable way to query a DB.